# C# ListView Label Edit - control selected text

Tags: c#, listview, text, edit

I am looking at the .Net Framework ListView (I've been trying BetterListView, the express version, and keep running up against things I can't do, so I figure I might as well run up against things I can't do in the better documented MS ListView!) and there's something that's stumping me.

I'd like the items to be editable, but I would like, when editing starts, for the selected text to be only part of the item text rather than all of it.

An example of this would be in Windows Explorer, when you have file extensions visible, and you start to rename a file - the file name is selected (blue background) but the file extension is not, such that if the user starts to type immediately then the name will be replaced but the extension stays as is.

I can think of workarounds, but wondered if there's any way to do that.

Comment: To clarify a bit, I'm looking for something like SelectionStart and SelectionLength from the TextBox (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_members(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: To clarify further, I only need to edit the main Item, not the SubItems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One long trawl through the appropriate messages, and the answer is...

```
private void listView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr editWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    editWnd = SendMessage(listView1.Handle, LVM_GETEDITCONTROL, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    int textLen = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(listView1.Items[e.Item].Text).Length;
    SendMessage(editWnd, EM_SETSEL, 0, (IntPtr) textLen);
}

public const int EM_SETSEL = 0xB1;
public const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
public const int LVM_GETEDITCONTROL = (LVM_FIRST + 24);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int len, IntPtr order);
```

That does exactly what I was after. Thanks for the other responders taking the time to answer.

Comment: I need this exact behavior but your solution doesn't work in my case that's strange...

Comment: I've also tried this code: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/11623/limit-text-entered-into-a-listview-edit-control (quite similar) and it works, but the selection setting doesn't. clue anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gridview for this. GridView has ItemEdit. also you can try some components like telerik or  devexpress..

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it right now, but of course that would lose the ListView functionality of having various layouts readily available. I wonder if there's some kind of SendMessage magic that can be worked...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ObjectListView here:  http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html  It is easy to use, very flexible and for the most part free.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've often looked at that control, and it probably does what I want, but if I understand GPLv3 (its license) correctly I would have to release the complete source code to my application. I'm fine with giving away the compiled code free, or free but with donations, but would prefer not to release the source code.

Comment: I have had the same conversation with the author.  I use the control in closed source projects.  As I recall he was not too concerned but I would recommend contacting him for confirmation.

Comment: You can use objectlistview in closed sourced projects (I do it all the time). The deal is that you should pay the author for the right to do this. It's a one time fee and I found it quite reasonable (I think $100 if I remember correctly).